# Bing safe search option is fixed to 'strict' and cannot be changed

Tags: bing

In the Bing.com, there is a safe search option.

[image: Bing safe search option]

I chose 'off' and clicked 'save' and then agreed to the age verification.
Of course I am an adult.

But this option still remains as 'strict'.

I did the same thing on the desktop and also on the mobile web browser.

How can I change this option?

Comment: The question doesn't look to include enough details. Please bear in mind that troubleshooting questions are not a good fit for this site as they tend to require a lot of back and forth but this site is not intended to be used that way. There are other sites that might allow this kind of question like [su], [apple.se].